# std::any object cast to reference type, change its value, but original object is not changed

Tags: c++, casting, reference, c++17, any

I was trying to see if std::any object can cast to reference type, and see whether changing the casted reference means to change original object. As below:

```
struct My {
    int m_i;
    My() : m_i(1) {}
    My(const My& _) : m_i(2) {}
    My(My&& m) : m_i(3) {};
    My& operator = (const My& _) { m_i = 4; return *this; }
    My& operator = (My&& _) { m_i = 5; return *this; }
};

int main() {
    any a = My();
    My& b2 = any_cast<My&>(a);
    b2.m_i = 6;
    cout << any_cast<My>(a).m_i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It prints `2`. For my I expected that, as long as `b2` is a reference, I hope changing `b2.m_i` will effect `a.m_i`, right? But result seems not as my expectation.

Where did I get wrong, is my expectation valid?

Thanks!

Comment: `cout << any_cast<My>(a).m_i << endl;` creates a copy of `a` and the copy constructor does `My(const My& _) : m_i(2) {}` ie it does not copy the value.  Change this line to `std::cout << std::any_cast<My&>(a).m_i << std::endl;` or implement the copy constructor correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your example without any `any`:

```
#include <any>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::any;
using std::any_cast;

struct My {
    int m_i;
    My() : m_i(1) {}
    My(const My& _) : m_i(2) {}
    My(My&& m) : m_i(3) {};
    My& operator = (const My& _) { m_i = 4; return *this; }
    My& operator = (My&& _) { m_i = 5; return *this; }
};

int main() {
    My a = My();
    My& b2 = a;
    b2.m_i = 6;
    cout << static_cast<My>(a).m_i << endl;
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/jcTGeYYjM) is:

```
2
```

Because `static_cast<My>(a)` is creating a temporary copy of `a` and your copy assigns `2` to the member. You can use `static_cast<My&>(a)` to not make a copy.

After removing your somewhat weird copy and assignment, you can also get the same result with `any`:

```
struct My {
    int m_i = 1;
};

int main() {
    any a = My();
    My& b2 = any_cast<My&>(a);
    b2.m_i = 6;
    cout << any_cast<My>(a).m_i << endl;  // copy
    cout << any_cast<My&>(a).m_i << endl; // no copy
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/snoEG5G9q):

```
6
6
```